# Include vanilla file in Wicket?

Tags: wicket

It would be useful to be able to include some vanilla text files, containing simple scripts (with no HTML-relevant content), in an HTML page in my Wicket portal. There's no end to support for .css and .js, but I would just like to drop simple text inside a

```
<pre>
...
</pre>
```

paragraph so that I don't have to keep copying and pasting when these change. Or, am I in too much of a hurry and have asked the wrong question?

Profuse thanks for any and all comments.

Later, ...

The answer I got triggered it for me. It was just what I needed. Unfamiliar as I am with Wicket, this was pretty much over my head. However, thanks to the marvel of Google and a more knowledgeable friend, I was able to get this going. A pretty thorough description of my complete solution can be found at http://www.javahotchocolate.com/notes/wicket.html. Thanks to Nicktar!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just give your pre-tag a wicket-id and fill it with a Label, setting EscapeModelStrings to false for the Label...